# Best Automation Frame work design

Tags: ui-automation

Using Nunit Frame work or Creating Visual studio Test Projects which one is the best way to save the time and effective automation?

Now i am using selenium IDE to script the maximum parts in my application to reduce the time of execution(i feel ide execution is faster than test project execution) using gotoif, while, regexp ..etc and would go Selenium RC only for data driven methods and the events which have not been handled by IDE.

Please suggest me Am i in the right way? because i am in the beginning stage on Automating my applications asking this Question for early correction is better.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't focus that much on execution time (unless it is really slow). nUnit vs MsTest is also not the biggest issue. In my opinion overall framework design will be most important.
You need to make it maintainable, extensible...
I would suggest the following readings on the framework design.

First blog from [Patrick Wilson](https://web.archive.org/web/20140221110745/http://patrickwilsonwelsh.com/?p=332) (via the wayback machine as the original link went down)

Second would be following materials:

- [Quick overview](http://www.teknologika.com/blog/building-the-next-generation-of-automated-tests/)
- [Bigger explanation](http://www.teknologika.com/blog/implementing-the-braidy-testers-automation-stack/)
- [Inspiration for all above and few pdf describing it](http://www.thebraidytester.com/stack.html)